# Binary Node Tree, wrong father and sons

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree

I'm having a hard time printing the following tree:

```
----------t1:---------- 
tree:(((1),2,(3)),4,((5),6,(7,(8)))) 
----------t2:---------- 
tree:(((1),2,((3),4)),5,(6,(7,(8)))) 
----------t3:---------- 
tree:((1),2,(3,(4,(5,(6,(7,(8))))))) 
----------t4:---------- 
tree:((((((((1),2),3),4),5),6),7),8)
```

where "father" have no parentheses and each "son" has a  bracket depends on the depth,the picture are the trees with depth.
here is my code:

```
private String toString(String acc,int length){


        if (left != null)
            acc =left.toString(acc, length + 1)+")"+",";

        // Adding two spaces 'length' times
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            acc +="";
        }

        // adding the object data and new space
        acc += this.data.toString();

        if (right != null)
            acc = "("+right.toString(acc, length + 1);

        return acc;
    }

public String toString() {
    return "("+toString("", 0)+")";
}
```

which instead prints:

```
   ----------t1:----------
tree:(((((1),23),45),678) 

----------t2:----------
tree:(((((1),23),4),5678) 

----------t3:----------
tree:(((((((1),2345678) 

----------t4:----------
tree:(1),2),3),4),5),6),7),8)
```

in the added picture, the tree is demonstrated with depth

[image: Binary Node Tree - the right result with depth]

Comment: The pattern is as follows: a tree ist printed by printing an opening paranthesis, the left subtree followed by a comma if there is a subtree, the tree's data, a comma followed by the right subtree if any, and a closing parenthisis. Printing the subtree is a recursive call to your method. The length parameter is not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, every node has an opening and closing parenthesis. As Stefan commented, you don't need the depth. Here's the code:

```
public String toString() {
    String out = "(";
    if (this.left != null) {
        out += left.toString() + ",";
    }
    out += this.data;
    if (this.right != null) {
        out += "," + right.toString();
    }
    return out + ")";
}
```

Comment: thank you! but what does this.value do exactly and what do i need to import to use it?

Comment: It was supposed to be this.data; Like Roger Edited. (ps, feel free to upvote my answer)